# How to pipe kubectl logs to an application on a remote server?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, remote-debugging

I want to call `lnav` application on remote server to view `logs`, but it doesn't work

```
kubectl logs mypod | ssh root@10.1.13.16 lnav # it doesn't work
kubectl logs mypod | ssh -t root@10.1.13.16 lnav # Passing the -t parameter still doesn't work

# ✘ error: unable to display interactive text UI
# reason: stdout is not a TTY
# = help: pass the -n option to run lnav in headless mode or don't redirect stdout
```

What should I do to use `lnav` remotely
https://github.com/tstack/lnav

```
lnav --version # lnav 0.11.1
```

Comment: Attaching a support [document](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/lnav-command-examples-in-linux/) for resolving your issue.

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde I have raised an `issue` with the developer, but there is no effective reply https://github.com/tstack/lnav/issues/1012    So I wonder if it is possible to realize this function through the `shell` so that it can work